# Grab uploading image in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension that checks if a person is trying to upload image from a webpage, this image is copied and uploaded by chrome extension.

I am trying to achieve this using `chrome.webRequest` - monitor the requests and try to find the image payload in base64. So far all of my efforts have failed.

The website I am playing with is using using `plupload.Uploader` to upload images so I really don't have a choice to play with the DOM and see how it works.

Here is what I am trying to do with my code

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (details){

    console.log(details)
}, {
    urls: ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    types: [ "xmlhttprequest"]
},
["requestBody"])
```

And the website is sending POST requests whenever I upload an image (screenshot attached)
[image]

So my questions are
1. Is this approach of mine to monitor outgoing requests for payload OK?
2. Does extension support what I am trying to do in here?

Comment: As you can see in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest) there's no such thing as `details.uploadData`. Also, I think it'd simply spoof XHR or fetch in a [page script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879) injected from a content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm sorry about the `details.uploadData` in the code. That was just meant for testing. So you are suggesting that I inject a content script in the code that monitors every xhr request that is going out of the page? I know we can inject a content script but how can we act from there?

Comment: Yes, see the link in my comment, and use it to insert a page script that spoofs XHR or fetch (examples can be easily googled).